# Invalid syntax on f-strings when run with gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, f-string

I have this flask api:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import mysql.connector
import environ
env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
environ.Env.read_env()


# import environment
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')
DB_PWD = env('DB_PWD')
FH_KEY = env('FH_KEY')
```

later on in the file, I have the lines below:

```py
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f'mysql://my-user:{DB_PWD}@localhost/my-db'
# several lines later
print(f'Message not routed: {data}')
```

When I run with the command `flask run ...` it works. But when I try to run it with `gunicorn ... api_daemon:app` I receive the following error:

```
File "/home/my-user/super_cool_app/api_daemon.py", line 35
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"mysql://my-db-user:{DB_PWD}@localhost/my-db"
                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I replace the `{DB_PWD}` with a simple string, the error moves down to the next f-string:

```py
File "/home/my-user/super_cool_app/api_daemon.py", line 89
    print(f'Message not routed: {data}')
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a reason f-strings would work when flask app is run with `flask run` but break when run with `gunicorn ... api_daemon:app`?

Raspberry Pi 4

Debian (Raspbian Buster actually)

python 3.7.3

gunicorn 19.9.0

Comment: Apparently you have multiple Python installations, and your `gunicorn` installation uses Python 3.5 or earlier where f-strings didn't exist. How did you install `gunicorn`?

Comment: I wish I could recall. PIP I imagine, but... 
`$ pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Comment: Actually, I apparently apt-got it lol. I uninstalled with apt and reinstalled with pip (pip3) and now it works. Thanks a ton, @Selcuk !!!